# wordpress form processing to custom post type not working

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-insert-post

I'm trying to insert a custom post type for a multiple image upload form.  The below code is the form processing.  The page is blank when i submit the form.  Where did i go wrong?

```
<?php       $art_title = $_POST['art_title'];

        $i = 0;
        foreach($art_title as $value) {
        $art_title = $_POST['art_title'][$i];
        $art_width = $_POST['art_width'][$i];
        $art_height = $_POST['art_height'][$i];
        $art_price = $_POST['art_price'][$i];
        $art_creation_date = $_POST['art_creation_date'][$i];
        $art_upload = $_FILES['art_upload'][$i];

        $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_title'][$i] = $art_title;
        $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_width'][$i] = $art_width;
        $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_height'][$i] = $art_height;
        $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_price'][$i] = $art_price;
        $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_creation_date'][$i] = $art_creation_date;


             $post = array(
              'post_content'   => '', // The full text of the post.
              'post_name'      => $art_title, // The name (slug) for your post
              'post_title'     => $art_title, // The title of your post.
              'post_status'    => 'draft', // Default 'draft'.
              'post_type'      => 'products', // Default 'post'.
              'post_author'    => '', // The user ID number of the author. Default is the current user ID.
              'menu_order'     => '0', // If new post is a page, sets the order in which it should appear in supported menus. Default 0.
              'post_password'  => '', // Password for post, if any. Default empty string.
              'post_excerpt'   => '', // For all your post excerpt needs.
              'comment_status' => 'open' , // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
              'post_category'  => '' // Default empty.
            ); 
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post); 
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id);
            add_post_meta($post_id, '_width', $art_width, true);
            add_post_meta($post_id, '_height', $art_height, true);

            $filename = $_FILES["art_upload"][[$i]["name"];
            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

            //file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
            $file_array = array(
                    'name'          => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['name'],
                    'type'          => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['type'],
                    'tmp_name'      => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['tmp_name'],
                    'error'         => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['error'],
                    'size'          => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['size']
            );

            // required for wp_handle_upload() to upload the file
            $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );

            if ( !empty( $file_array['name'] ) ) {
               // upload the file to the server
                $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $file_array, $upload_overrides );

                    // checks the file type and stores in in a variable
                $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploaded_file['art_upload'] ), null );       
                   // set up the array of arguments for "wp_insert_post();"
                $attachment = array(

                    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                    'post_title' => preg_replace('/.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $uploaded_file['art_upload'] ) ),
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_author' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'guid' => $uploads['url'] . '/' . $file_array['name']
                );

                // insert the attachment post type and get the ID
                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploaded_file['art_upload'] );
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                // update the attachment metadata
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
                $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id );
            }







        $i++;
        }
?>
```

This is how my full page looks.  Do i need to call a wordpress function?  What is missing?

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes still a blank page.. Do i need to require any files?  that is what the whole page looks like.  If so, what files do i need to require..

Comment: Does your code output anything to the page? What do you expect to see? Have you verified your data at each step to make sure its what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I've added echo "test"; and still nothing, when i inspect element with Google Chrome.  I've read this could be a fatal error.  When i remove the code, the echo "test"; is displayed??  I think this is due to calling wordpress functions. Do i need to include a file for wordpress functions to work?

Comment: I also check and the post isn't inserted.

Comment: If your code triggers a fatal error, you will see it printed on the page. Are you sure you have php debugging enabled?

Comment: Also I assume you arent trying to load a php file directly, that of course will not work.

Comment: yes, i've used both error_reporting and WP_DEBUG true and the page is blank.  Only when i remove the code then elements i've added are displayed.

Comment: how am i supposed to load the php file?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you have to target a WordPress page and hook your processing code to an action, like [`admin-post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_%28action%29).